# Read xml files from App.config file path?

Tags: c#-4.0, console-application

I have been on working windows console application to import xml data into database.
I am new to console applications, 
My requirement is i want to read xml file from folders, This paths are in the app.config --> appsettings. For ex: c:\Asset\XMl in the c drive assetfolder and XML is sub- floder contains some .xml files. These files need read from console.
Based on file path how to read xml files one by one(if exist file in folder) if not exist xml file in current folder go to next folder read the file if exist, after completion of reading file in a folder file need to move into another folder based on path mentioned in app.config.
How would i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

add the app.config using VS wizard.

add your values, for example

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <FilePaths>   
    <add name="MyKey" FilePaths="c:\Projects\XMLfolder\folder\abc.xml; c:\Projects\XMLfolder\folder1\xyz.xml"/>
  </FilePaths>
</configuration>
```

and then read it in the console application, for example:

```
string paths = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyKey"].FilePaths;

string[] splittedPath = paths.Split(';');

foreach(string currPath in splittedPath)
{
   // Your code here
}
```

Comment: I am not looking for connection string. I want to read xml file from folder based on the path

Comment: My requirement is i want to read xml file from folders, This paths are in the app.config --> appsettings. For ex: c:\Asset\XMl in the c drive asset folder and XML is sub- floder contains some .xml files. These files need read from console.

Comment: @Indra this isn't "do my work" site you know.... i gave you an example cus i though you were having hard time trying to read from app.config. but if you don't know how to open xml or search a folder i suggest u start googling